# if int(lista[2]) == 0: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, string

```py
import serial
import time
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#nombre del dispositivo serial : dmesg | grep -v disconnect | grep -Eo "tty(ACM|USB)." | tail -1
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
ser.flushInput()


def iluminacion (lista):
    #movimiento del robot
    dato = '5'
    #envio de las cordenadas gmail
    if int(lista[2]) == 0:
       
        correo_origen = '**********'
        contraseña = '******'
        correo_destino = '*********'
       
        a = "https://www.google.com/maps?q="
        b = lista[3]
        texto = a  + str(b)
       
        msg = MIMEText(texto)
        msg['Subject'] = 'COORDENADAS DE LA PERSONA '
        msg['From'] = correo_origen
        msg['To'] = correo_destino

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(correo_origen,contraseña)
        server.sendmail(correo_origen,correo_destino,msg.as_string())

        print(texto)

        server.quit()
       
       
    return dato
    return lista

while True:

    try:

        lineBytes = ser.readline()
        line  = lineBytes.decode('latin-1').strip()
        lista = line.split(',')
        print(lista)

        mensaje = iluminacion(lista).encode('latin-1')
        ser.write(mensaje)
        time.sleep(0.5)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Size of lista array is less than 3.

You are trying to access location of array(or list) which does not exist.

Index of array starts from 0 and end at size-1.

For example, if size of arr[] array is 5, then accessible locations are 0 to 4. If you try to access location 5 or greater than 5, then it will give you **Index Error**.

Comment: pero la lista tiene 4  valores["0", "0 ", "0", "0.00.000"] el problema es que la lista llamada line va moviendo sus valores osea primero muestra ["0", "0 ", "0", "0.00.000"] despues [ "0 ", "0", "0.00.000"] luego [ "0", "0.00.000"] y asi sucesivamente

Comment: You mean to say:-  'but the list has 4 values ["0", "0", "0", "0.00.000"] the problem is that the list called line is moving its values first, it shows ["0", "0", " 0 "," 0.00.000 "] then [" 0 "," 0 "," 0.00.000 "] then [" 0 "," 0.00.000 "] and so'.       _I can't understand Spanish. I Google Translated it._

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.